# Tips about spending 20 hours in Kiev airport

Tags: transit, lounges, kyiv

I've a layover of 20 hours including an overnight stay at Kiev airport next month. I'll be travelling Delhi-Kiev-JFK on Ukraine international airlines. From anyone acquainted with the airport, what are some tips to spend 20 hours in this airport? I saw that transit visa is not required, even on an Indian passport, but this is the longest transit time I've faced anywhere. I do have priority pass select membership, can I access the business international lounge without going through passport control? I'm assuming the lounge will be decent and will have wifi and charging stations as well as some food, but I'm not sure they allow someone to stay overnight or for 20 hours. I've unlimited lounge entries, so can enter repeatedly if they insist. I'm looking for other tips on making this transit as well. Due to hassles and the cost involved, I don't want to apply for a visa (even though Indians are eligible for visa on arrival) at this point.

Comment: Twenty hours is enough time to run the equivalent of a marathon in laps in the building.

Answer (score 0):

I’m going to assume that you are transiting at Boryspil airport, which is the larger of the two

I did LHR Kiev JFK.  With a 12 hour stopover.

I rather like Ukraine International. You get cheap tickets and two full pieces of hold luggage.  So it’s worth the wait.

I’ve not used the lounge.  But there was free WiFi all through.  Cafes were ok.

The airport is used to long stopovers so you should not have any trouble remaining airside.

My only issue was lots of smokers.   There is no designated smoking / non smoking area.  And I don’t smoke

Hopefully someone else can advise on the lounge

You might find this website useful.

https://www.sleepinginairports.net/guides/kyiv-boryspil-airport-guide.htm

Comment: "There is no designated smoking / non smoking area" Yikes, that still exists ?

Comment: My only complaint about a long wait in the transit area in Boryspil is the nonstop din of departing flight announcements all night long, which are all automated, play in the entire terminal, are extremely verbose, and are repeated once each in Ukrainian, English, and Russian.